# UISearchbar inside UITableView as the last cell hiding the keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` in which I have several custom cells and my last cell contains a `UISearchbar` in it. I have wired up the appropriate `delegates` and referencing `outlets` and can get the keyboard to show up. 
The problem I am facing is that the `searchbar` is at the very bottom of my `tableview` i.e. it is part of the very last cell. So even though the keyboard gets shown, the `searchbar` is hidden below it as I suspect it is unable to scroll to that location since its the last cell in the view. 
Does anyone have any thoughts on this and how to overcome this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to have your view controller be a subclass of `UITableViewController`. This type of view controller will handle issues exactly like these.

If you cannot, you should listen to keyboard will show/hide notifications and set `contentInset` and `scrollviewIndicatorInsets` bottom of the table view to the keyboard height. Then you can scroll the specific cell into visible. When the keyboard hides, set the bottom to the previous value.

Comment: Yes.. Just changed it to UITableViewController.. I had old code where I needed this to be a UIViewController, but that is no longer the case. Best to go with available solutions than hack your way through a system. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Yes....Two ways

1) either you can change the frame of whole `tableView` and pull the whole table up by decreasing the **y position** of `tableView`

```
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
```

or

2) You can change the `contentOffset` of the table to programatically scroll the tableView's last cell so that it is visible to the user.

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,400) animated:YES]
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: `contentOffset` is not a very correct solution, because you scroll the table view more than it should. When the keyboard hides, the view will "jump" to correct offset. This is an ugly transition.

Comment: before that you can increase the contentSize  [tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0,400)].

Comment: What is "400"? Hard coded values are never a good idea. What if the view is loaded on an iPad?

Comment: 400 is just an example..I am not telling to hard code anything, we can calculate the contentoffset and then apply it so that it will scroll to the last cell.